# Automatically display the Console as a SwiftUI View, or create a View to show a log of messages

Tags: swiftui, swift-playground

I have an app in Swift-Playgrounds on my iPad, but I'd like to display a log of text lines in the lower half of the screen, just like the built-in Console.

The problem is, I can't see how to show the open Console by default. Once my app is running I have to click the orange Swift logo, click 'Show Console' and 'Done', then click the icon to expand it. It then works fine, displaying the lines I 'print' from my code.

Alternatively, what sort of SwiftUI view can I use to display lines of text, ideally that will scroll when it fills the view, although I don't mind writing code to manage that, if needs be.

Comment: Alternatively, how about a `ScrollView { Text(your-stuff-here) }`, not too difficult to implement.